# qTip2 - display tooltip when any DOM object is created

Tags: jquery, qtip2

I am working around with `qTip2` for tooltips, and I have a situation where I want to display several tooltips on the screen, but I want them to appear whenever a corresponding DOM element is created.

The element is created as a result of a third party tool, and I am not capable of controlling it.

I have spent days going over the documentation and trying the examples, but I cannot seem to produce this. I very simply want to have a tooltip appear whenever a given element of a certain class is created, and for the tooltip to display the contents of one of its HTML attributes.

Is this conceivable? I can only find answers that relate to clicking or hovering an element that already exists, nothing I can find seems to correspond to new ones that might appear later on.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to trigger the tooltip by using the `trigger` method to fire a mouseover event.

using the example from [the documentation](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/):

```
$('ul:last li.active').qtip({
   content: 'This is an active list element',
   show: 'mouseover',
   hide: 'mouseout'
})
```

you could trigger the tooltip with

```
$('ul:last li.active').trigger('mouseover');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an event called `DOMNodeInserted` than can help you.

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
    $(e.target).qtip({...});
});
```